# Reading data into struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, readfile

How would I get data from a text file straight into a pointer of structs? Im trying this but I cant get it to work, example of the text file can be:

A 100

K 55

C 300, etc

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct myStruct
{
    char singleChar[10];
    int height;
};

int main (void) {

    FILE * fp;
    char buffer[50];
    int counter = 0;
    char a[10];
    int res;
    int b;
    struct myStruct **list;
    list = malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct));

    fp = fopen("test.txt","r");  
    while (fgets(buffer,50,fp)!= NULL)
    {
        res = sscanf(buffer, "%c%d",a,&b);
        if (res == 2) 
        {
            list[counter] = malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct));
            strcpy(list[counter]->singleChar,a);
            list[counter]->height = b;
            counter++;
        }
    }

    printf("%d",list[0]->height);

    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Your listing seems incomplete and garbled. The definition of *struct MemoryQueue* is missing. Also the type definition of list looks odd to me - Apparently you want it to be an array of pointers to myStruct. Then define it as *struct myStruct *list[LISTSIZE]*.

Comment: Sorry, I was changing the naming around. Also I cant set the list size because I'm not supposed to have that prior knowledge. Thats why I need the **

Comment: Now think about what you want to store in *list* (pointers to *myStruct*) and what you allocate for *list* (one single *myStruct*)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the size of the file you will have to do a full pass on it to determine its length and afterwards scan it again to load the data into the structs:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct myStruct
{
    char singleChar[10];
    int height;
};

int main (void) {

    FILE * fp;
    int counter = 0;
    char a[10];
    int b, i;
    int file_length = 0;

    fp = fopen("test.txt","r");
    while (fscanf(fp, "%c%d\n",a,&b) > 0){
        printf("%c,%d\n",a[0],b);
        file_length += 1;
    }
    printf("There are %d entries\n",file_length);

    struct myStruct *list[file_length];

    fclose(fp);
    fp = fopen("test.txt","r");
    while ( fscanf(fp, "%c%d\n",a,&b) > 0 ){
        list[counter] = malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct));
        strcpy(list[counter]->singleChar,a);
        list[counter]->height = b;
        counter += 1;
    }

    for ( i = 0 ; i < file_length ; i++ ){
        printf("%c,%d\n",list[i]->singleChar[0],list[i]->height);
        free(list[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

An alternative approach would be to allocate use realloc.

Why are you using an array of char inside the struct instead of a single char?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a linked list :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct List
{
char c;
int i;
struct List* lp;
};

typedef struct List LinkedList;
_Bool first_time_here=1;

LinkedList *head,*tmp;

int main(void)
{

char tempc,nl;
int tempd;
LinkedList* ptr;
LinkedList* current=NULL;
FILE* fp; 

if((fp=fopen("36229327.txt","r"))!=NULL)
{
  printf("Contents from file\n");
  while(fscanf(fp,"%c%d%c",&tempc,&tempd,&nl)>0)
    {
          printf("%c %d\n",tempc,tempd);
      ptr=malloc(1*sizeof(LinkedList)); 
      if(ptr != NULL)
      {
      if(first_time_here)
      {
      head=ptr;
      first_time_here=0;
      }
      ptr->c=tempc;
      ptr->i=tempd;
      ptr->lp=NULL;
      if(current!=NULL)
       {
         current->lp=ptr; 
       }
      current=ptr;
      }
      else
      {
      printf("Can't allocate memory\n");
      printf("Aborting\n");
      }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    printf("\nFile Closed\n\n");
if(head!=NULL)
{
current=head;
printf("File contents retrieved from Linked List\n");
while(current!=NULL)
{
  printf("%c %d\n",current->c,current->i);
  tmp=current;
  current=current->lp;
  free(tmp); // clearing the allocated memory
}
}
}
else
{
printf("Can't open file\n");
exit(-1);
}

return 0;
}
```

As evident from the code memory is created on demand and freed after use.

**Assumption** : The file contents are stored exactly as given in the question
with no extra spaces at the end of the line.